# Is it possible to use the Firebase Storage Emulator from Cypress within a GitLab pipeline?

Tags: firebase, gitlab, cypress

I am trying to test a Vue3 application using Cypress within a GitLab pipeline. I am using the Storage emulator.

The code to store the file looks like the following:

```
import { getStorage, uploadBytes, ref as StorageRef, listAll } from '@firebase/storage';

function storeFile() {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const storageRef = StorageRef(storage, "tests/some-child40"));
    const blob = new Blob(['foo'], {
        type: "text/plain",
    });

    uploadBytes(storageRef, blob).then((snapshot) => {
        console.log("Uploaded a blob or file!");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Upload failed", error);
    });
}
```

On my local machine, that works well.

However, within GitLab I get the following error message:

[image]

The file is not being stored. What is does the error code `501` mean?

I have inspected `firestore-debug.log` but it does not provide more information.

I have properly setup the storage emulator using `connectStorageEmulator(storage, 'localhost', 9199);`

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I'm facing something similar.